How to know if a rocketry product is real/safe?
I found this website yesterday: Trajectory Aerospace It seems like a new small business selling rocketry products for quite cheap. I would like to use some of these products for my project but I am unable to understand whether:

Are the products real?
Are they safe and usable for model rocketry?
Should I buy from such websites?


ok, thank you! I'll test the products and let you know. Apparently the electrical tape is supposed to distinguish between the different classes but seems slightly weird.

In terms of prices, note that looking at the ingredients for sale these are https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket_candy that someone is selling NOT model rocket motors (and therefore probably expensive for what they are). Have changed my assessment to from 'not a scam' to the possibly more problematic 'will post you a handmade explosive device shaped like a rocket motor'. If this in fact your business you are trying to advertise would suggest a LOT more work on proving compliance with shipping/handling rules (eg max order sizes, safety sheets) and up front performance numbers.

hi! this is not my business. I see why you may think so, but I need those rocketry parts for my project. Thank you for your comment.

Don't remove the content of your question. Also if not for the fact that you are an experienced user of this site, I would think that this is a spam seed.

I can't comment because my rep is too low but this seems like a blatant advertisement to me and sale of pyrotechnics in India without a NOC is illegal it needs to be linked I think
Rule 103 Explosive Act 1883  The NOC (No object certificate) from the concerned police department needs to be very explicitly linked at the bottom of the website. but that can't happen since NOCs are not given to websites...
After 26/11, these sites have been shut down before first shipment, and the same must happen here...
Sale of such equipment that too without a proper contracting system and buyer verification in our country is VERY illegal. I work in the customs department and I've NEVER ever seen something this blatantly ignorant. Sale of pyrotechnics in India is NOT done over website.
To whoever owns this website, take it down. It won't be pretty if your package gets caught up and opened.

Hi, and welcome to space SE. I suspect you are right, but is it possible to add links to the rules around shipping home made fireworks in India, and/or any rules around possession of these devices?

@GremlinWranger, I have edited the question and added all the information I have. Thank you
